# Create a list of vectors from a vector where n consecutive values are not 0 in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, while-loop

So I have this vector:

```
a = sample(0:3, size=30, replace = T)
 [1] 0 1 3 3 0 1 1 1 3 3 2 1 1 3 0 2 1 1 2 0 1 1 3 2 2 3 0 1 3 2
```

What I want to have is a list of vectors with all the elements that are separated by n 0s. So in this case, with n = 0 (there can't be any 0 between the consecutive values), this would give:

```
res = c([1,3,3], [1,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3], [2,1,1,2]....)
```

However, I would like to control the n-parameter flexible to that if I would set it for example to 2, that something like this:

```
b = c(1,2,0,3,0,0,4)
```

would still result in a result like this

```
res = c([1,2,3],[4])
```

I tried a lot of approaches with while loops in for-loops while trying to count the number of 0s. But I just could not achieve it.

**Update**

I tried to post the question in a more real-world setting here:
[Flexibly calculate column based on consecutive counts in another column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480412/flexibly-calculate-column-based-on-consecutive-counts-in-another-column-in-r)

Thank you all for the help. I just don't seem to manage put your help into practice with my limited knowledge..

Comment: To be able to reproduce your `sample` data, please use `set.seed`. That said, I think your vector 'b' is more than enough to demonstrate the problem - just use that throughout ;) Also, whenever the word 'consecutive' is used, it smells `rle`. Check it!

Comment: This probably needs to be focused on a specific programming problem, you should add code you've tried to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `rle` + `split` for general cases, i.e., values in `b` is not limited to `0` to `3`.

```
with(
  rle(with(rle(b == 0), rep(values & lengths == n, lengths))),
  Map(
    function(x) x[x != 0],
    unname(split(b, cut(seq_along(b), c(0, cumsum(lengths))))[!values])
  )
)
```

which gives (assuming `n=2`)

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4
```

---

If you have values within ragne `0` to `9`, you can try the code below

```
lapply(
  unlist(strsplit(paste0(b, collapse = ""), strrep(0, n))),
  function(x) {
    as.numeric(
      unlist(strsplit(gsub("0", "", x), ""))
    )
  }
)
```

which also gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to paste a somehow useful solution with the function `SplitAt` from DescTools:

```
SplitAt(a, which(a==0)) %>% lapply(., function(x) x[which(x != 0)])
```

where a is your intial vector. It gives you a list where every entry contains the pair of numbers between zeros:

[image: 1st solution]

If you than add another SplitAt with empty chars, you can create sublist after sublist and split it in as many sublists as you want: e.g.:

```
n <- 4
SplitAt(a, which(a==0)) %>% lapply(., function(x) x[which(x != 0)]) %>% SplitAt(., n)
```

gives you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sample(0:3, size=30, replace = T)
a
[1] 0 3 2 0 1 0 2 2 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1

a2 <- paste(a, collapse = "") # Turns into a character vector, making it easier to handle patterns.
a3 <- unlist(strsplit(a2, "0")) # Change to whatever pattern you want, like "00".
a3 <- a3[a3 != ""] # Remove empty elements
a3 <- as.numeric(a3) # Turn back to numeric
a3
[1]     32      1 221122  11112      2      1      1
```